# IOS Swift TableView edit action for row at index path

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, editing

I would like to know if there is an option to close the editing menu in the table view (as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrZbH.png)) which we get when we swipe to right. I want the menu to close as soon i select an option, in my case it does not close even when i select any one of the option. It closes only when i select anywhere on the screen.

Below is my code which im using

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let update = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Update") { action, index in
        print("update")
    }
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("Delete")
       
    }
    return [delete, update]
}
```

[image]

Comment: try calling `self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` in your action block? You may need to enable it afterward though

Comment: @Tj3n Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just reload the particular cell and it's close the option.

For that you can use following code may this solve your problem.

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Also you can use

```
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Happy coding.